# Does the Thing from Fantastic Four regenerate lost body parts or lost stone/skin?

Tags: marvel, fantastic-four, the-thing

I can't seem to find the answer by Googling, and it's bothering me a bit too much.

Does he regenerate lost body parts or lost stone/skin? Never read comics that much so I have no idea.

Comment: Related: Not dupe - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93853/has-thing-ever-bled

Answer (score 3):

I have found no listed source of a healing factor. And, to quote [the other question linked above](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93853/has-thing-ever-bled):

> In a battle against Wolverine (Fantastic Four vol. 1, #374 (Mar. 1993)), his face was cut open by Wolverine's Adamantium claws and bled. The claws left scarring that Ben would later wear a helmet to hide the scars. He was later healed by Hyperstorm.

[image: Wolverine cutting Ben]

[image: Depicted scarring]

On the other hand, he does heal normally, probably at a human rate, as he has had chunks of his stone skin knocked off which have grown back, and he [apparently does not age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thing_(comics)#Powers_and_abilities) as discovered in *Fantastic Four #605*, which suggests some level of cellular regeneration (or possibly simply no cellular mutation or shortening of telomeres).