# Can Mjölnir get dirty?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, mjolnir

So I saw a mod for a game which added Mjölnir and in the comments someone was complaining that the textures used were too clean. So I started wondering if it could get dirty or rust or something like that? As far as I know, you never see it happen in the MCU but I have to say that I never really paid that much attention to it.

Comment: We do require one to stick to one universe. Futhermore we don't really do mythology questions, that would be more appropriate for [mythology.se] so I guess in this case the answer will have to be in the MCU or comics :)

Comment: Oh I see... I've only just discovered the mythology one so I'll try there and edit this question to be only for MCU :)

Comment: Dust and mud are not worthy of Mjolnir.

Comment: We know it gets blood on it. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93853/has-thing-ever-bled/93877#93877

Answer (score -4):

Dirty like covered of mud? Yeah, Mjölnir continues been a *thing*; but rust?! No way, man.. We're talking about one of the most powerful weapons of MCU and Marvel Comics..

Comment: Do you have anything to back this up, aside from the fact that it's powerful? And what do you mean when you mean that mud is a *thing*?

Comment: @Thunderforge sorry, man.. I think there is no post or comic that speaks specifically about the relationship between Mjölnir and rust; and about mud be a thinh, I wrote the grammar.. ma' bad!

Comment: You can always edit your answer if you find anything, or to correct your grammar. Alternatively, if you choose to delete your answer, you will get the [Peer Pressure](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/peer-pressure) badge as a consolation.